# Minimum GCC version that officially supports C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile

What is the minimum version of GCC that officially supports the C++11 standard? I am asking this because I want to modify my Makefile.am so that it builds a certain target binary only when the system compiler supports C++11.

The Makefile pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
if GCC compiler version >= minimum GCC version that supports C++11
    bin_PROGRAMS += program_that_needs_cpp11_to_compile
endif
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11

Comment: You will also get useful information on cppreference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp11)

Comment: and how do i get the minimum gcc version that uses at least C++11 by default (without any use of -std=c++XY flag)? thank you so much, unslander and damien.

Comment: There is no such version. Please read the cxx-status page. The next default standard bump was to C++14.

Comment: GCC 6.1 uses C++14 by default, earlier versions use C++03